# How to configure Castle Windsor to use the same grand-child objects on a single build-up

Tags: castle-windsor

Castle Windsor creates multiple instances of grand child objects using transient lifestyle.

Object A has a dependency on C1 and C2.
C1 and C2 both have a dependency on GC.

On buildup:

- Using StructureMap only 1 instance of GC is created and passed to both C1 and C2.
- Using Castle.Windsor a new instance of GC is created for C1 and C2 - ie 2 instances.

In my case GS is managing a nHibernate session, and C1 and C2 are repositories used by domain class A.

Castle Windsor is returning 2 sessions causing cross session data errors.

Answer (score 0):

Those are semantics of transient - each time a new instance is provided. StructureMap uses custom lifestyle here.

Why are you using transient lifestyle here? Wouldn't per-web-request (if you're running in a web app) be much more appropriate?

If you're not running in a web app, you probably should have some other unit-of-work (like a screen) that you bind your session to via custom lifestyle.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Krzysztof,

We're using this in a batch application where I want 1 session per "logical" unit of work.
In a web app I'd use the WebApp lifestyle (or for SM Cache by HttpSession).

Really all I want is transient with "common" children. So for a 2nd build up, I'd get a new GC. I can create a custom lifestyle but that's a lot of work (relatively).

Does CW provide access to the "root" object or other build up instance so I can control here.

Thanks,

SB

PS - I'd challenge that StructureMap uses a custom lifestyle here.

Comment: I don't think there's any easy way to do it. I once did a spike to play with idea of explicit scope in Windsor - you might find the code useful. https://gist.github.com/400979 https://gist.github.com/400980